# Wordpress custom wp_pagenavi does not work on custom page with custom query

Tags: wordpress, navigation

I am trying to do some custom page and I am not using the wp_pagenavi plugin but a custom function with my custom pages, right now it only works on index.php pages but it was working fine some days ago before I've added more query elements.

```
//custom pagepavi function
function my_pagenavi( $the_query = false ){
  global $wp_query;
  $query = ($the_query) ? $the_query : $wp_query;
  $max = $query->max_num_pages;
  $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged')); 
  $big = 999999999; 
  if ( $max > 1 ) { 
        echo "<div class='pagination' style='height:auto'>";
        echo paginate_links(array(
              'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),  
              'format' => '?paged=%#%',
              'current' => $current_page,
              'show_all'     => false,
              'total' => $max, 
              'type' => 'list',
              'prev_text' => __('PREV','dnp_theme'),
              'next_text' => __('NEXT','dnp_theme'), 
        ));  
        echo "</div>";
  }
```

}

Now here is the loop from my template page.

```
  //some query stuff
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $query = 'offset=0&paged='.$paged;

  $blogs = new WP_Query($query);

  if ( $blogs->have_posts() ) : ?>              

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>

        <?php while ( $blogs->have_posts() ) : $blogs->the_post(); ?>
              <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php my_pagenavi( array('query' => $blogs) ); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Why is not loading anything? What is going on??

Answer (score 0):

The query is not correct that is why it's not working, at least it was not, not I have it working fine :)

instead of

```
$blogs = new WP_Query($query);
```

and all that should be

```
$blogs = query_posts( 'post_type=post&posts_per_page=4&paged='.get_query_var('paged') );
```

the loop is just like any other and works perfect

```
  if ( have_posts() ) : ?>              

        <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
              <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php my_pagenavi(); ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

**after endwhile write this code**

global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(

```
'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),

'format' => '?paged=%#%',

'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),

'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
```

) );